# using was cognito identity id to protect my rest end points via hmac?

Tags: javascript, spring, rest, amazon-web-services, hmac

Can I use AWS Cognito IdentityID as HMAC key on SSL to protect my REST services?

I would like to secure and setup the following application.

1. A HTML/Javascript client using AWS Cognito (future plans to sync across clients) on an SSL Page
2. A Spring Boot REST app
3. AWS DynamoDB

So the flow would be:

1. I setup the javascript buttons for google+, amazon and Facebook logins and grab the AWS Cognito token.
2. Once I have the Cognito ID, I make a call to my user service (/user/auth) and see if the user exists using the ID. If they don't I create a profile record in DynamoDB. (cognito id is the key)
   If they exist I can look up the user profile in dynamoDB and get their authorisation to be used in Spring Security.
3. I want to now secure all calls to my service with HMAC by using the Cognito ID.

is this safe?

Can I just add spring security on top of Spring boot and implement HMAC checks? If so how? Why isn't this in spring already via OAUTH?

thanks in advance.